# Shared XDR routines and pointer to .rodata section

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault, xdr

I used rpcgen to generate the client and server stub for program I'm developing. So, the stubs use XDR to encapsulate data and send them through the net. When I execute this piece of code, a segmentation fault is thrown:

```
char *str = "Hello!";
my_remote_call(str, strlen(str));
```

Instead, no problems if I modify it in this way:

```
char *str = "Hello!";
char *str2 = (char*) malloc(strlen(str));
memcpy(str2, str, strlen(str));
my_remote_call(str2, strlen(str2));
```

With GDB I found the segmentation fault is generated in the xdr_u_char() function called by my_remote_call(). My question is:

in the first case the Hello string is allocated in the .rodata section by compiler while in the second a part of heap is used to memorize the string. Might the segmentation fault be generate because the xdr_u_char signature require explicitly

```
char*
```

and not a

```
const char*
```

as you can see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fxdr_u_char.htm)? So in this case means that the xdr_u_char() function changes my data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is changing data when it is receiving, and not sending, it. Are you sure your remote call is indeed using XDR with `XDR_ENCODE` mode?

Comment: I think so because the server should print some infos when the corresponding server-side function is called. And no infos are printed.

Answer (score 0):

To transmit string to XDR you should use `xdr_string` not `xdr_u_char`; show us the `*.x` file for `rpcgen`  ...

Comment: I know, I know, you're right, but it was only an example. The problem is that the string I'm handling are not NULL-terminated. I just wanted to understand the cause of segmentation fault. Sorry, I couldn't show the .x file, it for my thesis and there're some legal constraints on. :(

Comment: You could debug, using the debuggable variant of the `libc`; on a Debian or Ubuntu system, install the `libc6-dbg` package and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately. And you should look at the source code of the XDR portion of `libc`.